# Undo event in CKeditor

Tags: ckeditor

I have faced in CKEditor slow response when we triggered undo event, if more than 1000 paragraphs
    Ex:

```html
<p>1</p><p>2</p><p>3</p>....<p>1000</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the beforeCommandExec event and check for the undo and redo events. Something like this where editorInstance is and CKEDITOR instance.

```js
    editorInstance.on('beforeCommandExec', function(e){
        if(e.data.name === 'undo') {
            // handle before undo
        }
        if(e.data.name === 'redo') {
            // handle before redo 
        }
    });
```